# Multiple labels per item on Kendo chart

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, kendo-ui-angular2, kendo-chart

I'm trying to get multiple label per item on Kendo Column chart
Desired layout looks like this
[image: desired chart]

I was able to get only this layout

```typescript
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { groupBy, GroupResult } from '@progress/kendo-data-query';
import { ValueAxisLabels } from '@progress/kendo-angular-charts';

export type TrendItem = {
  clientName: string;
  periodName: string;
  income: number;
};

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
        <kendo-chart>
          <kendo-chart-category-axis>
              <kendo-chart-category-axis-item [categories]="categories">
              </kendo-chart-category-axis-item>
          </kendo-chart-category-axis>

          <kendo-chart-value-axis>
              <kendo-chart-value-axis-item [labels]="valueAxisLabels">
              </kendo-chart-value-axis-item>
          </kendo-chart-value-axis>

          <kendo-chart-series>
            <kendo-chart-series-item *ngFor="let groupedResult of groupedTrendsByPeriod" [data]="groupedResult.items" field="income" type="column">
              <kendo-chart-series-item-labels [content]="labelVisual">
              </kendo-chart-series-item-labels>
           </kendo-chart-series-item>
          </kendo-chart-series>
        </kendo-chart>
    `,
})
export class AppComponent {
  public valueAxisLabels: ValueAxisLabels = {
    font: 'bold 16px Arial, sans-serif',
  };

  public trendItems: TrendItem[] = [
    {
      clientName: 'Client1',
      periodName: 'Q1 2020',
      income: 20,
    },
    {
      clientName: 'Client1',
      periodName: 'Q2 2020',
      income: 15,
    },
    {
      clientName: 'Client1',
      periodName: 'Q3 2020',
      income: 35,
    },
    {
      clientName: 'Client1',
      periodName: 'Q4 2020',
      income: 40,
    },
    {
      clientName: 'Client2',
      periodName: 'Q1 2020',
      income: 15,
    },
    {
      clientName: 'Client2',
      periodName: 'Q2 2020',
      income: 20,
    },
    {
      clientName: 'Client2',
      periodName: 'Q3 2020',
      income: 15,
    },
    {
      clientName: 'Client2',
      periodName: 'Q4 2020',
      income: 30,
    }
  ];

  public categories = (groupBy(this.trendItems, [{ field: 'clientName' }]) as GroupResult[])
    .map((e) => e.value);

  public groupedTrendsByPeriod = groupBy(this.trendItems, [{ field: 'periodName' }]) as GroupResult[];

  public labelVisual(e: { dataItem: TrendItem }) {
    return `$${e.dataItem.income}\r\n${e.dataItem.periodName}`;
  }
}
```

You can try this code [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hsczmx?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts).

My current result look like this
[image: current progress]

---

So my question is how to display multiple labels per item like on the first picture?

---

My current obstacles.

- I didn't find a way to add multiple `<kendo-chart-series-item-labels>` elements. Only one will be rendered, rest will be ignored.
- I didn't find a way to position labels below column chart. For column chart it's only possible to use "center", "insideBase", "insideEnd", "outsideEnd" options (according to [API Reference](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/charts/api/SeriesLabelsPosition/)) but none of them gives me desired position.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the notes feature of the KendoChartComponent.

You can see the implementation [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hsczmx-g6ufdt?file=app/app.component.ts).

1. You add `noteTextField="periodName" [notes]="notesOptions"` to your `kendo-chart-series-item` element.
2. You add `[labels]="labelOptions"` to your `kendo-chart-category-axis-item` element.
3. You add the following to your component:

   ```
   public notesOptions = {
       position: 'bottom',
       icon: {
           visible: false,
       },
       label: {
           color: 'black',
           content: (e) => e.dataItem.periodName,
           font: "12px Arial",
           margin: -30,
       },
       line: {
           width: 0,
       },
   };

   public labelOptions = {
       margin: {
           top: 10,
       },
   };
   ```
4. Change the `labelVisual` function return value to `` `$${e.dataItem.income}\` ``.

**Note:** Some changes can be performed and still give the desired design so if something isn't exactly right, it's probably fixable.

Here is an image of the resulting chart:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think **kendo** provides any native solution for that but what I can suggest is to:

1. Use legends to display each bar meaning. like the example [here](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/bar-charts/column).
2. Use some self generated labels and position them under the table which is risky for UI. I provided an example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hsczmx-n49cnw?).